# How to get meta-data from audio file

Tags: c++, qt

I write some media player. This is piece of my code:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyClass(QMediaPlaylist * p):playlist(p){}
private:
    QMediaPlaylist *playlist;
    QList<QMediaContent> mediaContent;
    QStringList trackList;
public slots:
    void addToPlaylist (const QList<QUrl> & urls){
        for(int i = 0; i < urls.length(); ++i){
            mediaContent.push_back(QMediaContent(urls[i]));
            //trackList.append("Author - title");
        }
        playlist->addMedia(mediaContent);
    }
};
```

I need to get meta-data info from each of object in playlist. I thought that I can achieve this using QMediaPlaeyer class, but, I guess, this won't be very optimal. Is any other way to get meta-data from playlist object? Using QMediaPlayer class would be troublesome, cause there is no method wich add object to MediaPlayer and get url or QMediaContent as argument.